# PHP script is not working while reading and writing a text file

Tags: php

Just for practice I have written this small code for saving username and password to a text file. This is the code:

```
$fh = fopen("de.txt", 'a+') or die("");
$text = "username =" . $uide . "password =" . $pwd ."\n";
$contents = fgets($fh);
if( strpos($contents, '$uide') !== false) && 
strpos($contents, '$pwd')  !== false) )
{
    break;
}
else {
fwrite($fh, $text) or die();
}
```

What I basically wanted to do is that read from a text file check whether a username and password already exists or not, if not then to save it and if it is already there then to discard it and execute further script, but I am having a bit of a problem here.

It is not saving the credentials, and from the day I added this code to my script my entire script  stopped working. I tried all sort of solution in my knowledge but none of them seems to solve this. Can anyone help me with the problem?

**EDIT:** I have edited the code as given in answer and it is working but it still has a problem. It only works for the first username and password and rest all are still being copied. I mean the credentials are saved in the text document in following manners

> **username** = batman  **password** = not-found
>
> **username** = spiderman **password** = pepper
>
> **username** = spiderman **password** = pepper

So I am saying that the credentials of the first line will not be saved again in the text but all the things after that still keeps on repeating, can anyone tell why is that?

Comment: a few suggestions. 1. define "stopped working", do you have any error code or observations? 2. try and narrow down your problem by putting loglines after every single line of code so you know exactly which line is causing trouble.
if you manage to figure out those 2 things then you can probably fix it yourself

Comment: yes i was executing this code by cron, and every time i started the cron it failed with HTTP error 500 can you figure out what is the problem--- there was no detailed log of about what or which line was causing the problem that's why it is hard for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have error reporting enabled? Because the error is very clear when I try to use your code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 7

And if I look at line 7 I see this:

```
if( strpos($contents, '$uide') !== false) && 
strpos($contents, '$pwd')  !== false) )
```

The first problem is your parenthesis are not balanced. Changing it to this fixes that immediate issue:

```
if( strpos($contents, '$uide') !== false && 
strpos($contents, '$pwd')  !== false)
```

Or if you want to add another layer of parenthesis to each condition you could do this, but it's unneeded for the logic you have in place:

```
if ((strpos($contents, $uide) !== false) &&
    (strpos($contents, $pwd)  !== false)) {
```

Then you have a few other issues in your code. Such as why are there checks for `strpos` with the values `'$uide'` as well as `'$pwd'`. When you place single quotes like that, it’s a literal value of `'$uide'` and `'$pwd'`. So that should be changed to this:

```
if(strpos($contents, $uide) !== false && 
strpos($contents, $pwd)  !== false)
```

And here it is in your full code as presented with a bit of formatting cleanup:

```
$fh = fopen("de.txt", 'a+') or die("");
$text = "username =" . $uide . "password =" . $pwd ."\n";
$contents = fgets($fh);
if (strpos($contents, $uide) !== false &&
    strpos($contents, $pwd)  !== false) {
break;
}
else {
fwrite($fh, $text) or die();
}
```

Formatting might not ever seem like a big deal, but simple code syntax errors like this often get revealed and cleaned up by simply formatting the code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help i am just a noob in php this is my  second code. But i am still having a problem it is still saving duplicate username and pass can you help me

Comment: yeah you are right thanks you were a grate help I was stuck on this for a week Thanks again

Comment: Sorry forgot to to check it as accepted did it now, I have edited my question according to problem i am facing again can you solve it thanks

Comment: It has nothing do with script same happens if i run the code alone , If that help otherwise thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

`'$uide'` is just the string `'$uide'`, not the variable, you should remove the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Does it help?

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("de.txt", 'a+') or die("");
$text = "username =" . $uide . "password =" . $pwd ."\n";
$contents = fgets($fh);
if( strpos($contents, $uide) !== false && strpos($contents, $pwd)  !== false ){
    break;
} else {
    fwrite($fh, $text) or die();
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax error in if condition, your if condition is not properly closed (check extra brackets), it should be::

```
if( strpos($contents, '$uide') !== false && strpos($contents, '$pwd')  !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

all is good, just replace this two lines,

```
if( strpos($contents, $uide) !== false) && 
strpos($contents, $pwd)  !== false) )
```

because in this your variable was considered as a string with dollar's